# Auto create S3 Buckets on localstack

Tags: amazon-s3, docker-compose, localstack

Using localstack in my docker-compose mainly to mimic S3.

I know I can create buckets, that's not the issue. What I would like to do is automatically create the buckets when I run a docker-compose up.

Is there something built in already for localstack?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

A change that came in with this [commit](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/commit/4544ad59dffd9b00b84b96ad2450eb6e6c024b46) since version `0.10.0`.

> When a container is started for the first time, it will execute files
> with extensions .sh that are found in `/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d`.
> Files will be executed in alphabetical order. You can easily create
> aws resources on localstack using awslocal (or aws) cli tool in the
> initialization scripts.

**Before v1.1.0**

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
      # - "4572:4572" Old S3 port
    volumes:
      - ./aws:/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d
```

**After v1.1.0**

> The `/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d` directory usage has now been deprecated. The Pluggable initialization hooks in `/etc/localstack/init/<stage>.d` have replaced the legacy Init scripts, and the former will be removed entirely in the 2.0 release.

Reference: [localstack/localstack/issues/7257](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/7257)

Init hooks [official documentation](https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/init-hooks).

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
    volumes:
      - ./aws:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d
```

With a script in directory `./aws/buckets.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
awslocal s3 mb s3://bucket
```

Will produce this output:

**Before v1.1.0**

```
...
localstack_1  | Starting mock S3 (http port 4572)...
localstack_1  | Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
localstack_1  | Ready.
localstack_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/buckets.sh
localstack_1  | make_bucket: bucket
localstack_1  |
```

**After v1.1.0**

```
localstack-1  | Ready.
localstack-1  | 2023-01-05T18:07:50.163  INFO --- [-functhread8] l.services.motoserver      : starting moto server on http://0.0.0.0:40443
localstack-1  | 2023-01-05T18:07:50.165  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_0] localstack.services.infra  : Starting mock S3 service on http port 4566 ...
localstack-1  | 2023-01-05T18:07:50.324  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_0] localstack.request.aws     : AWS s3.CreateBucket => 200
localstack-1  | make_bucket: bucket
```

Comment: The script part of the answer is slightly wrong. The `mb` and `s3` are the wrong way round! Should be `awslocal s3 mb s3://bucket`. Thanks for the answer though, saved me a lot of hassle!

Comment: @MattKeen where is the directory `docker-entrypoint-initaws.d` and its contents (`.sh` scripts) supposed to be created in the localstack container? I've tried creating it in `/usr/local/bin/` and `/opt/code/localstack/`, but it doesn't look like the `.sh` scripts are getting run when the container starts.

Comment: They should be in `/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d`, therefore `./aws/buckets.sh` would be `/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/buckets.sh`, based on the configuration above.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. Do you have any idea how I can set my healthcheck to wait for this bucket to be created ?

Comment: This might work as a test for healthcheck  `test: "awslocal s3api head-bucket --bucket bucket"`

Comment: One little sidenote: localstack needs aws cli credentials. So either set them within the script or as env-variables in the compose file.

Script:
```export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=foobar
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=foobar```

Comment: Looks like `/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d` is deprecated. See below answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74819396/9711710 for more information and updated solution.

Answer (score 8):

I have been able to achieve this using Localstack with kind of "workaround":

1. Start Localstack
2. Create expected buckets, e.g.:

   ```
   aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3 mb s3://test1
   ```
3. Above line will update the `s3_api_calls.json` file in the Localstack directory (by default on Linux it's
   `/tmp/localstack/data`
4. Backup the file
5. Put the copied file in the Localstack directory ( `/tmp/localstack/data` by default) before starting the stack again
6. You should be able to see something like `2019-03-21T08:38:28:INFO:localstack.utils.persistence: Restored 2 API calls from persistent file: /tmp/localstack/data/s3_api_calls.json` the in startup log after you start Localstack again and the bucket should be available: `aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3 ls s3://test1`

Answer (score 7):

#### Important notice for users of LocalStack v1.1.3 and above

Since the 1st of December 2022, LocalStack has announced the deprecation of legacy init scripts (`/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d`) with the release of [v1.3.0](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/releases/tag/v1.3.0). The replacement - [plugggable initialisation hooks](https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/init-hooks/) - was introduced in v1.1.0.

They will be **[fully removed](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/7257)** in v2.0.0, posing a risk for anyone that would be using `/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d` with the latest version of LocalStack.

**This would be a breaking change.**

For future-proofing, the accepted answer is still valid but I would recommend replacing `/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d` with `/etc/localstack/init/ready.d`.

This would mimic the previous intended behaviour, as it would be hooking into the `READY` stage where LocalStack can actually create your S3 buckets, while making sure you can still continue to update LocalStack.

This would be the best current `Dockerfile`:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
    volumes:
      - ./aws:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d
```

Answer (score 0):

Just spend a day making it right. Here we go!

The goal is: run docker-compose with localstack, create S3 bucket s3://this-is-my-bucket and copy over some json files from project source

LOCALSTACK_BUILD_VERSION: latest today, 2.1.1.dev

**Docker compose:**

```
localstack:
  image: localstack/localstack:latest
  networks:
    - hmpps
  container_name: localstack
  ports:
    - "4566-4597:4566-4597"
    - 8999:8080
    - 9080:9080
  environment:
    - SERVICES=s3
    - PORT_WEB_UI=9080
    - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
    - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
    - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    - DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-2
  volumes:
    - "./src/test/resources/test-data:/tmp/localstack/test-data"
    - "$PWD/src/test/resources/localstack/setup-s3.sh:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh"
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

**Two important things here:**

1. src/test/resources/test-data               -  is the source folder for your json files
2. src/test/resources/localstack/setup-s3.sh  -  is a script file to run during docker-compose

[image]

**Script file setup-s3.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
export TERM=ansi
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=foobar
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=foobar
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-2
export PAGER=

echo "S3 Configuration started"

aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 mb s3://this-is-my-bucket
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 cp /tmp/localstack/test-data/ s3://this-is-my-bucket/chart --recursive

echo "S3 Configured"
```

Look at **"--recursive"** param for "aws cp" command.
That took us 4 hours!

Does not work without "**--recursive**". Crazy!

**logstack docker logs:**

```
2023-06-22 17:07:00 S3 Configuration started
2023-06-22 17:07:01 2023-06-22T16:07:01.070  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_0] localstack.request.aws     : AWS s3.CreateBucket => 200
2023-06-22 17:07:01 make_bucket: this-is-my-bucket
2023-06-22 17:07:01 2023-06-22T16:07:01.431  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_0] localstack.request.aws     : AWS s3.PutObject => 200
upload: ../../../tmp/localstack/test-data/1a.json to s3://this-is-my-bucket/chart/1a.json
2023-06-22 17:07:01 S3 Configured
```

**UI for localstack S3 buckets is here**
http://s3.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/this-is-my-bucket
[image]

**Not sure if required, we have application-test.yml properties**

```
aws:
  region-name: eu-west-2
  endpoint-url: "http://localhost:4566"
  access_key: foobar
  secret_access_key: foobar
  s3:
    access_key: foobar
    secret_access_key: foobar
    bucket_name: this-is-my-bucket
```

Next goal is to write an integration test, point to localstack s3://this-is-my-bucket bucket, load "chart/1a.json" file, and run the assertion magic.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

DATA_DIR: Local directory for saving persistent data (currently only supported for these services: Kinesis, DynamoDB, Elasticsearch, S3)